# How to search and edit an xml tag that matches a condtion using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, substring, xmlstarlet

I am in need of a solution using xmlstarlet to search for a xmltag based on a condition and edit its xmltag value.

My command

```
xmlstarlet ed -N a="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "/a:project/a:properties/a:ifm.core_system_ui.version[.=contains(.,'3.700.999')]" -x "concat(translate(substring-before(.,','),'8','7'),',',substring-after(.,','))" pom.xml
```

I have crafted the xmlstarlet command to search and replace the xmltag value under `/properties/ifm.core_system_ui.version` but I need our communities help to develop this command to search for the xmltag under `<properties>` that has it name that ends with  `version>` and edit the value under that tag

Sample pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<properties>
        <ifm.core_system_ui.version>[3.800.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.core_system_ui.version>
        <ifm.fault_ui.version>[3.800.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.fault_ui.version>
        <ifm.ifm_admin_ui.version>[3.800.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.ifm_admin_ui.version>
        <ifm.ifm_grouping_ui.version>(3.800.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.ifm_grouping_ui.version>
        <ifm.ifm_config_archive_ui.version>(3.800.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.ifm_config_archive_ui.version>
        <xmp_nbi_static_content.version>(17.1.8, 18.1.999)</xmp_nbi_static_content.version>
        <helpdesk_ui.version>[3.95.0,3.95.999)</helpdesk_ui.version>
        <someother>[7.77.0,8.88.888)<someother>
</properties>
</project>
```

Expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<properties>
        <ifm.core_system_ui.version>[3.700.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.core_system_ui.version>
        <ifm.fault_ui.version>[3.700.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.fault_ui.version>
        <ifm.ifm_admin_ui.version>[3.700.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.ifm_admin_ui.version>
        <ifm.ifm_grouping_ui.version>(3.700.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.ifm_grouping_ui.version>
        <ifm.ifm_config_archive_ui.version>(3.700.0, 3.800.999)</ifm.ifm_config_archive_ui.version>
        <xmp_nbi_static_content.version>(17.1.8, 18.1.999)</xmp_nbi_static_content.version>
        <helpdesk_ui.version>[3.95.0,3.95.999)</helpdesk_ui.version>
        <someother>[7.77.0,8.88.888)<someother>
</properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since xmlstarlet can't use the XPath 2.0 function `ends-with()`, you could try using `substring()` to check the end of the name...

Try replacing:

```
a:ifm.core_system_ui.version
```

with:

```
*[substring(name(),string-length(name())-string-length('version')+1)='version']
```

Here's the updated command (untested)...

```
xmlstarlet ed -N a="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "/a:project/a:properties/*[substring(name(),string-length(name())-string-length('version')+1)='version'][.=contains(.,'3.700.999')]" -x "concat(translate(substring-before(.,','),'8','7'),',',substring-after(.,','))" pom.xml
```